# How to give current user full access control permissions for the installed application Program files folder

Tags: wix, wix3

I'm new to WiX. Using WiX v3.0.

I want to create one installer for the application.

If I install the application, it is installed in `C:\Program Files\Appln\`.
I want to give *full access control* to the `Appln` folder while installing my application.

Is it possible? I don't want to manually set the full access control permissions for the folder.

Comment: If your application is designed for *per-user*, then you can switch the installer from *per-machine* install to *per-user*. In this way, the application is installed into user's profile, and therefore the user has full write permissions to the app folder.

Answer (score 2):

First, this isn't a recommended design. The user should not be able to modify things in `ProgramFilesFolder` for a great many reasons. However, you can do this with the `Permission` element. It'd look a little like:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
   <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
      <Directory Id='ApplnFolder' Name='Appln'/>
   </Directory>
</Directory>

<Component Id='GrantTooManyPermissionsToApplnFolder' Directory='ApplnFolder'
           Guid='PUT-GUID-HERE'>
   <CreateFolder>
      <Permission GenericAll='yes' User='[UserSID]' />
   </CreateFolder>
</CreateFolder>
```

The important parts are the `CreateFolder` and `Permission` elements. `CreateFolder` defaults to the `Directory` of the `Component` and gives a place to hang the `Permission` element. The `Permission` element is pretty self-explanatory. The `UserSID` property is a [built-in MSI property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This also means, the application would not work correctly under another user account.

Comment: That's true. This is a really poor design. You could grant access to `Everyone` instead of the `UserSID` but that just makes it even *less* secure.

Comment: It's not secure. I just wanted to highlight another issue the OP could face with this approach.